# Google Calendar Sync 403 Forbidden

Tags: php, google-calendar-api, http-status-code-403, google-api-php-client

I am making an application that syncs google calendar events.

My issue is with updating a google event, when i try to do this i get a 403 Forbidden error with no other details.
Weirdest thing of all is that i can get the events, create them, but not update them. I know about the possibility of the user not being able to edit the event but in this case the user is the owner of the calendar so that should not apply. I am using the google api v3 for php.

Actual error: Error calling PUT https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events/_eventId: (403) Forbidden

I have already tried to share the calendar to the email address in the google console, that didn't help, also tried to do the update without the token in offline mode, but with no success.

Any help or suggestions are welcomed, i have spent too much time researching this with no solutions so I am out of ideas now.

EDIT: Code used:

```
        //For the client we use the token with refresh token
        $googleAccount = $this->getGoogleAccountRepository()->findOneBy(['user' => $user]);
        $client = $this->getClient($user, $googleAccount,$group);
        $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
        $calendarId = "primary";
        // First retrieve the event from the API.
        $eventRetrieved = $service->events->get($calendarId, _eventId);
        $event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event($eventRetrieved);
        $event->setSummary(_newSummary);
        $event->setDescription(_newDescription);
        $start = new \Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
        $start->setDateTime(_someDatetime->format(\DateTime::RFC3339));
        $end = new \Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
        $end->setDateTime(_someDatetime->format(\DateTime::RFC3339));
        $event->setStart($start);
        $event->setEnd($end);
        $event->setLocation(_newLocation);
        try{
            $updatedEvent = $service->events->update($calendarId, $eventRetrieved->getId(), $event);
        }
        catch(\Google_Exception $ex)
        {
            return;
        }
```

Comment: can you show us the code that you are using to make this call?

Comment: Are you using service account or 3-legged oauth? If it is service account, you need to use domain wide delegation https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation. Also, are you sending the correct event_id you wanted to update. Please check https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/update your sample request here which helps to know whether issue is with your code/API. I tried updating event in my calendar,it worked fine.

Comment: Try also updating the sequence number to one higher or clear the sequence number field ;)